# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null in Apache Cordova in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, visual-studio, cordova

I am getting this error while building the solution in apache cordova in Visual Studio.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: please, get more information about problem. maybe dome code or stacktrace of exception

Comment: When I am creating a new project this error is showing